# raster function in raster package produces errors from examples code

Tags: r, raster

I am having trouble with the raster function in the raster package today - it worked fine for me recently.

When I run the example code from the help file:

```r
library(raster)
#from scratch
r1 <- raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=0, xmx=10)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘res’ for signature ‘"BasicRaster"’
```

I have confirmed that I don't have another package loaded with a function called raster, however, the function 'res' exists in both the terra and raster packages. I have tried using the conflicted package to set both terra and raster packages as the preferred package for 'res' using the code below.

```
conflicted::conflict_prefer(name = "res", winner = "terra")
```

below is the output of sessionInfo()

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Denver
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape2_1.4.4    ggExtra_0.10.1    extrafont_0.19    readxl_1.4.3      cowplot_1.1.2    
 [6] raster_3.6-26     tidyr_1.3.0       vegan_2.6-4       lattice_0.21-8    permute_0.9-7    
[11] data.table_1.14.8 elevatr_0.99.0    stars_0.6-4       abind_1.4-5       sp_2.1-1         
[16] sf_1.0-14         dplyr_1.1.3       ggplot2_3.4.4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0   viridisLite_0.4.2  farver_2.1.1       fastmap_1.1.1      reshape_0.8.9     
 [6] promises_1.2.1     digest_0.6.33      mime_0.12          lifecycle_1.0.3    cluster_2.1.4     
[11] ellipsis_0.3.2     terra_1.7-55       magrittr_2.0.3     compiler_4.3.1     rlang_1.1.1       
[16] tools_4.3.1        utf8_1.2.3         yaml_2.3.7         knitr_1.45         FNN_1.1.4         
[21] labeling_0.4.3     bit_4.0.5          classInt_0.4-10    curl_5.1.0         plyr_1.8.9        
[26] KernSmooth_2.23-21 miniUI_0.1.1.1     withr_2.5.1        purrr_1.0.2        grid_4.3.1        
[31] fansi_1.0.5        xts_0.13.2         xtable_1.8-4       e1071_1.7-13       colorspace_2.1-0  
[36] progressr_0.14.0   extrafontdb_1.0    scales_1.2.1       MASS_7.3-60        cli_3.6.1         
[41] rmarkdown_2.25     crayon_1.5.2       intervals_0.15.4   generics_0.1.3     cachem_1.0.8      
[46] DBI_1.1.3          proxy_0.4-27       stringr_1.5.0      splines_4.3.1      parallel_4.3.1    
[51] cellranger_1.1.0   vctrs_0.6.4        Matrix_1.6-3       bit64_4.0.5        units_0.8-4       
[56] glue_1.6.2         codetools_0.2-19   gstat_2.1-1        stringi_1.7.12     gtable_0.3.4      
[61] later_1.3.1        munsell_0.5.0      tibble_3.2.1       pillar_1.9.0       htmltools_0.5.7   
[66] R6_2.5.1           conflicted_1.2.0   automap_1.1-9      evaluate_0.22      shiny_1.8.0       
[71] memoise_2.0.1      httpuv_1.6.12      class_7.3-22       Rcpp_1.0.11        nlme_3.1-163      
[76] Rttf2pt1_1.3.12    spacetime_1.3-1    mgcv_1.8-42        xfun_0.41          zoo_1.8-12        
[81] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add your session information with `sessionInfo()` to the OP? I just ran your code without any error using `raster_3.6-26`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that.

```
library(raster)
#Loading required package: sp

r1 <- raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=0, xmx=10)

showMethods(res)
#Function: res (package terra)
#x="BasicRaster"
#x="SpatRaster"
#x="SpatRasterDataset"

packageVersion("raster")
#[1] ‘3.6.26’
```

I assume that you are using old and incompatible versions of terra/raster. I would first update terra and then raster.

If that does not help, then please edit your question and show everything that is printed in your session after `Type 'q()' to quit R.` (if anything). (When you see `[Previously saved workspace restored]` you know you are in trouble.)  And include what is returned by `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Updating Terra solved the issue